# Android VideoView thumbnail refresh after programmatically seeking on certain devices

Tags: java, android, thumbnails, android-videoview, onpause

In my application I sometimes have to programatically skip the video to a certain position according to user input.

The problem I'm having is that when the video is paused and I seek to a specified value the thumbnail does not refresh (the videoview still displays the image where it was initially paused).

This however happens only on devices such as the Galaxy S4, the HTC One or the Nexus 10 (maybe something related to the API or the resolution, not exactly sure), while it works as expected on Galaxy S2, Nexus 7 and other lower-end devices.

I've tried a "hacky" approach such as starting and pausing the video with no success (the image in the videoview does not update).

I'm hoping that someone with a bit more experience can tell me if there is any way to refresh the video's thumbnail programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `SeekOnCompletedListener` of the underlaying `MediaPlayer` of the `VideoView` and pause right after it seeked.

```
void Seek(int position) {
    VideoView1.start();
    VideoView1.seekTo(position);
}

VideoView1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new MediaPlayer.OnSeekCompleteListener()  {

                    @Override
                    public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            VideoView1.pause();                 
                    }

                });
            }

        });
```

Comment: Everytime onPrepare fired up, you are creating new instance of seek complete listener... It should work, take care about performance